# И снова это "и"

Tags: пунктуация, и

"И(,) словно в подтверждение этих слов, небеса разразились ливнем".

Всегда теряют в таких вот случаях, когда "и" стоит в начале предложения. Много раз видел, что авторы не ставят здесь запятую. Кто-нибудь может пояснить и обосновать? Буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта: (1) **И, словно в подтверждение этих слов,** небеса разразились ливнем. (2) **И словно в подтверждение этих слов,** небеса разразились ливнем.

Присоединительный союз И в начале предложения может отделяться или не отделяться запятой от сравнительного оборота, как и в случае других синтаксических конструкций (авторское решение). **Обособление оборота с двух сторон способствует его выделению, также может зависеть от его** распространенности:

**И словно ветры счастья**, в мое окно стучатся лишь воспоминания. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)].

**И, как немые жертвы гроба**, Они беспечны были оба!

**И, словно шрапнель,** взорвались все запахи, все цвета, голоса, картинки минувшей, не такой уж и великой, жизни ...[Илья Бояшов. Танкист, или «Белый тигр» (2008)]

И, **словно яркая стоматологическая лампа**, поднятая специальной штангой так, чтобы весь ее свет падал в рот пациенту, в небе над городом горела полная луна. [Виктор Пелевин. Тарзанка (1994)]